# Proper way to seperate piece of code as a background process

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a bullCollections where I save some information about some messages example

```
try {
    let bullPayload = {
        type: 'message',
        payload: {
            messsages: messagesForPreProcessingData,
            sessionID: this.data['sessionID'],
            socketID: parseInt(this.data['socketID']),
        },

        await bullConnections[accumulatorQueue].add(bullPayload, {
            removeOnComplete: true,
        });
    };
```

The code works fine but I was asked to change the logic here, according to some statistics the messages are taking too much time to be shown to some users ( from bad wifi) and I come up with a solution that the front end will calculate the time taken from server to client and if that took longer than 400ms a new request will be sent so that the backend will know that the messages took a long time to load.

I made a timeout like this

```
saveBullPayloadWithTimeout(key, timeDuration, bullPayLoad, messages, events) {
    let redis = this.data.dbRedisConfigur.dataRedis;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            redisConnections[redis].get(key, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    if (result) {
                        redisConnections[redis].del(key, (err, result) => {
                            if (result == 1) {
                            } else {
                                logErrors({ message: 'CANNOT DELETE KEY' });
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        bullConnections[accumulator].add(bullPayLoad, {
                            removeOnComplete: true,
                        });
                        console.log('AFTER');
                        this.updateCurrentMessages(messages, events);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, timeDuration);
    });
}
```

So this piece of code should wait for 5 seconds so that it can know whether to insert the message or not.
During these 5 seconds, the backend waits for a second request if a second request has been made it saves data to Redis and after 5 seconds it will check that data if it exists then it won't save the message otherwise it will save it.

Does timeout affect the performance, because the backend will handle millions of users?

Is there any better way to separate this as a background process?

Comment: Is your question *"Proper way to seperate piece of code as a background process"* (your title) or *"Does timeout affects the performance, because the backend will handle millions of users"* (the end of your text)? Those don't seem to be related; `setTimeout` doesn't do anything in even another thread, much less *process*. (Also: A sentence asking a question in English should end with a question mark [`?`].)

Comment: I made an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does timeout affect the performance, because the backend will handle millions of users?

Timeouts, themselves, probably won't affect performance much. But your specific use of them will, because all it does is delay the process by `timeDuration` and then run it **on the main thread**, and you don't have anything in there (as far as I can tell) to cancel a previous one if a subsequent request is made that supercedes it.

> Is there any better way to separate this as a background process?

`setTimeout` **doesn't** do its work as a background process. It doesn't even do it on a background thread. It's done on the same main thread that scheduled the timer. Using `setTimeout` just delays starting the work, it doesn't make the work happen on a different thread.

If you want something done in a different *process*, you'll need to spawn a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

If you want something done on a different thread, you'll need to spawn a [worker thread](https://v).

Comment: @Crowder if  i put the setTimeout to null so it can be garbage collected and prevent memory leak , will this work?

Comment: @Dren - I don't know what you mean by *"put the setTimeout to null"*. `setTimeout` is a function, and what it returns (in browsers) is a number (on Node.js it's an object). Setting either of them to `null` won't do anything. If you want that work to be cancelled, use `clearTimeout`, but again, all your current code is doing is delaying the work, it is **not** putting it on a different thread or in a different process.

Comment: Yeah I know that actually but , because i ve tested this code to and it caused memory leak as i predicted but is there a way to prevent memory leak in this case?

Comment: @Dren - Sorry, the code in the question is too fragmentary to help you with that. But fundamentally: Remove the `setTimeout` or handle cancelling it at some appropriate point. And if you want to actually do that work on a different thread, do that.